# What is the recommended way of showcasing user public profiles in other websites?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have user public profile as a functionality. I need to provide the users with some code that he can integrate in other websites and showcase his profile to public. Basically my idea is to have a script that embeds a clickable image on other websites and if anybody clicks on it he is taken to the users profile in a new tab or new window.

I am not aware of any other apps that does similar way. Any examples also would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have him copy paste html.

Something like:

```
<a href="profile-link" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" ><img src='image-link' /></a>
```

target="_blank" opens the linked document in a new window or tab
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Link_types

rel="nofollow" indicates that the content links to an unendorsed document, like a paid link.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a#Attributes

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. I was thinking of a JavaScript solution rather than html soultion. Which one is more practically used?

Comment: HTML is more practical and will be more friendly to other sites.

Comment: @Baconator507 Dont refer W3Schools.com, please read this http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @Ravi interesting, ill replace the links

Comment: I can't find better links =(

Comment: [target at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a#Attributes). [nofollow at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Link_types).

Answer (score 2):

you can use target attribute. 
target [MDN Anchor target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a)

> This attribute specifies where to display the linked resource. In
>   HTML4, this is the name of, or a keyword for, a frame. In HTML5, it is
>   a name of, or keyword for, a browsing context (for example, tab,
>   window, or inline frame). The following keywords have special
>   meanings:

1. `_self`: Load the response into the same HTML4 frame (or HTML5 browsing context) as the current one. This value is the default if the attribute is not specified.
2. `_blank`: Load the response into a new unnamed HTML4 window or HTML5 browsing context.
3. `_parent`: Load the response into the HTML4 frameset parent of the current frame or HTML5 parent browsing context of the current one. If there is no parent, this option behaves the same way as _self.
4. `_top`: In HTML4: Load the response into the full, original window, canceling all other frames. In HTML5: Load the response into the top-level browsing context (that is, the browsing context that is an ancestor of the current one, and has no parent). If there is no
5. `parent`, this option behaves the same way as _self.

   ```
    <a href="profile-link" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src='image-link' /></a>
   ```

use `rel="nofollow"` to protect the user from spam.

Comment: +1 for rel="nofollow"

Comment: How does it protect the user from spam? I don't know about other search engines, but I'm pretty sure Google still follows links with `rel="nofollow"` but notes that you don't 'endorse' where the link goes, and if some spambot wanted to follow that link, it's going to, no matter what attributes you put on that link.

Comment: @icktoofay i agree. but as the syntax can do the trick . putting a two line syntax will not cost more. hope if google stops following based on rel attribute :)

Comment: All well behaved search engines [honor nofollow](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96569).